# Сравнение объектов с дочерними коллекциями C#

Tags: c#, .net, сравнение

Друзья, стоит задача сравнить два списка объектов и вывести разницу в тех полях, в которых она есть.

Проблема состоит в том, что одно из полей - вложенная коллекция.

Пример, есть класс XMLModel и коллекция с XMLPeriod:

```
public class XMLModel
{
    public string Famaliya { internal get; set; }
    public string Imya { get; set; }
    public string Otchestvo { get; set; }
    public string Snlis { get; set; }
    public List<XMLPeriod> Periods { get; set; } 
}

public class XMLPeriod
{
    public string StartPeriod { get; set; }
    public string EndPeriod { get; set; }
    public string Lgota { get; set; }
    public string TU { get; set; }
    public string OUT { get; set; }
    public string PostitionList { get; set; }
    public string Dekret { get; set; }
    public string Visluga { get; set; }
    public string VislugaStavka { get; set; }
}
```

Я честно говоря, даже не знаю с какого боку подступиться. 
Реализовать сравнение объектов в первом приближении можно наверное, через IEquatable так:

```
public class XMLModel : IEquatable<XMLModel>
{
    public string Famaliya { internal get; set; }
    public string Imya { get; set; }
    public string Otchestvo { get; set; }
    public string Snlis { get; set; }
    public List<XMLPeriod> Periods { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(XMLModel other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return
            string.Equals(Famaliya, other.Famaliya, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(Imya, other.Imya, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(Otchestvo, other.Otchestvo, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(Snlis, other.Snlis, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            !Periods.Except(other.Periods).Any();
        ;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (Famaliya != null ? Famaliya.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Imya != null ? Imya.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Otchestvo != null ? Otchestvo.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Snlis != null ? Snlis.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Periods.Distinct().Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode()));
            return hashCode;
        }

    }
}


public class XMLPeriod : IEquatable<XMLPeriod>
{
    public string StartPeriod { get; set; }
    public string EndPeriod { get; set; }
    public string Lgota { get; set; }
    public string TU { get; set; }
    public string OUT { get; set; }
    public string PostitionList { get; set; }
    public string Dekret { get; set; }
    public string Visluga { get; set; }
    public string VislugaStavka { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(XMLPeriod other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return
            string.Equals(StartPeriod, other.StartPeriod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(EndPeriod, other.EndPeriod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(Lgota, other.Lgota, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(TU, other.TU, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(OUT, other.OUT, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(PostitionList, other.PostitionList, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(Dekret, other.Dekret, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(Visluga, other.Visluga, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(VislugaStavka, other.VislugaStavka, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (StartPeriod != null ? StartPeriod.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (EndPeriod != null ? EndPeriod.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Lgota != null ? Lgota.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (TU != null ? TU.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (OUT != null ? OUT.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (PostitionList != null ? PostitionList.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Dekret != null ? Dekret.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Visluga != null ? Visluga.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (VislugaStavka != null ? VislugaStavka.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

}
```

Для того, чтобы понять как сравнить два объекта XMLModel, я сравниваю 4 поля, реализую интерфейс IEquatable в XMLPeriod, и в  Equals у XMLModel проверю содержание списков !Periods.Except(other.Periods).Any();

Все это даст только факт того, что они разные. Как пойти дальше, и в случае имеющейся разницы, найти ее и отобразить?

Comment: У вас получается, что Пупкин А.А. с двумя периодами и Пупкин А.А. с тремя периодами - разные объекты?

Comment: Можно просто по СНИЛСу сравнивать

Comment: @Ruslan Artamonov, все верно. Но хочется посмотреть в чем же разница. Потому что Equals, может посчитать разными , даже если два периода. Например, разные значения полей PostitionList. Вот эту разницу и хочется видеть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно реализовать через Reflection

```
public class XMLPeriod
    {
        public string StartPeriod { get; set; }
        public string EndPeriod { get; set; }
        public string Lgota { get; set; }
        public string TU { get; set; }
        public string OUT { get; set; }
        public string PostitionList { get; set; }
        public string Dekret { get; set; }
        public string Visluga { get; set; }
        public string VislugaStavka { get; set; }


        // получение свойств, которые не совпадают
        public List<PropertyInfo> GetDifference(XMLPeriod other)
        {
            return
                typeof (XMLPeriod).GetProperties().Where(x => !x.GetValue(this).Equals(x.GetValue(other))).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Дальше приспособьте, как вам надо, потому что не понятно как вы хотите сравнивать лист с листом. Все со всеми, или по порядку, или искать минимальное различие, или сравнивать те, у которых какое-то поле совпадает. Надо вам подумать еще.